# No se reconoce el metodo repaint() dentro de un timer

Tags: java, netbeans, interfaz-gráfica, checkbox

Este código me funciona en el constructor de mi jframe, me imprime una imagen en un  label.
Ahora tengo un checkbox y al ser presionado quiero que ponga la imagen por un segundo por ello el timer pero me marca error el método repaint() me pide el Netbeans cree el método dentro del actionlistener, no se como solucionarlo.
aquí mi código en el action performed del checkbox:

```
    private void simulacionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        if(simulacion.isSelected()){
            t = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            ImageIcon imagen0 = new ImageIcon("src/imagenesmedidor/menora50.jpg");
            Icon icono0 = new ImageIcon(imagen0.getImage().getScaledInstance(medidor.getWidth(),medidor.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
            medidor.setIcon(icono0);
            this.repaint();
            }
        });

        }
```

Comment: Deberías poner cual es tu problema porque no lo tengo claro. No has puesto cúando llamas el método `simulacionActionPerformed()` y según lo tienes implementado no te va a funcionar nunca porque lo único que hace es crear `listeners` que no agregas nunca a un componentes que genere el evento. Primero deberías leer bien [cómo funcionan los eventos en Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html) para poder entenderlos .

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque antes de pedir ayuda se debe hacer un estudio sobre el tema, adquirir una base mínima y exponer todo lo que se ha intentado. La pregunta es difícilmente recuperable por no seguir ni de lejos la documentación oficial.

Answer (score 0):

Estas llamando a `this` desde una clase anónima (diferente a la que implementa o extiende de JFrame).

Para hacer referencia a la clase y al propio objeto en el que estas, tendrías que sustituir `this.repaint();` por `nombreClase.this.repaint();`, "nombreClase" lo sustituyes por el nombre de tu clase, la que implementa JFrame, así te reconocerá `this` de la manera que tu quieres, si no he entendido mal.

Comment: Agradezco a todos su comentarios, aun soy nuevo. En java y mi mestro es un mediocre, por lo que me he visto en contratiempo para aprendizaje en el lenguaje, logré soluciónar el problema, entiendo que para un foro de este ámbito mis conocimientos del tema aun están fuera de alcanze. Gracias a todos.